Error CVT1108 cannot open RES....tmp for writing intermittently appearing on DevOps pipeline
I have a pipeline building my C# application using Visual Studio 2019. Occasionally when building the solution, I get the following error.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\al.exe /culture:da /out:obj\Release\da\MyApp.resources.dll /platform:AnyCPU /template:obj\Release\MyApp.exe /embed:obj\Release\MyApp.Properties.Resources.da.resources
##[error]CVTRES(0,0): Error CVT1108: cannot open C:\Users\WP2BUI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RES161C.tmp for writing

The filename is always different (but it's always RESxxxx.tmp) and if I look on the server in the specified directory, there are a large number of these RES....tmp files, however the ones reported by this error message all appear to have a size of 0 bytes.
An internet search for the error message turns up multiple hits but in each case, it amounts to ensuring the build agent has write privileges to that directory. I don't feel like this is the answer in this case, as I've checked and the user does seem to have write privileges, and I would imagine if this was the problem it would fail every time.
Two other things I should point out.

There are many developers using this pipeline - it's a Continuous Integration pipeline used for pull requests.

When I build the application on my own machine and monitor the same dir, the RES....tmp  file appears briefly and disappears, which makes me think VS should be deleting it after use. However, on the build server, there are hundreds of these files left over from a few months' worth of builds.


Edit
This error appears below the above. Not sure if it's caused by the above error or is the cause of it - but in case it matters:

CVTRES : fatal error CVT1108: cannot open C:\Users\WP2BUI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RES161C.tmp for writing [c:\agent_work\56\s\src\MyApp\MyApp.csproj]
##[error]ALINK(0,0): Error AL1019: Metadata failure while creating assembly -- The specified image file did not contain a resource section.

Another Edit
It is always al.exe which fails with the above error, and always on resources files. The application has 12 different languages, and al.exe runs for the resources on each one. The one on which it fails seems random.

What type of user is running the Windows Service for the agent? Are there multiple agents on the same box, and do they share the same user? Is the user an admin on the box?

However, on the build server, there are hundreds of these files left over from a few months' worth of builds - see Visual Studio 2022 adds an overwhelming amount of folders into %TEMP%: Is it safe to delete them?.

@gunr2171 - The user is an administrator. There is only one agent currently active (there's a second using the same user but it's disabled).

Hi@komodosp， can you please try to build the solution on the agent directly without using the azure devops pipeline? You can use the Visual Studio 2019 , msbuild  or dotnet build.  This helps narrow down the issue.  By the way, in the pipeline, if you are using the VSBuild@1 task, you can try to use the  DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to see if the same error happens.

@MiaoTian-MSFT - I have built the solution a number of times now on the server - (but using my user rather than the build agent's user) with msbuild and not encountered the error. I have occasionally (not on all builds) that the odd time one of the RES*.tmp files gets left behind in my Temp folder

Ran DirectoryMonitor on the folder, and lots of RES*.tmp files are created, and deleted immeadiately (I presume once for each running of al.exe) - however one of them was down as "New" then "Modified" rather than deleted... this was one that was left behind in the Temp folder after the build was complete. Wondering why this one was modified while all the others were deleted.

Hmm... wondering now if it's possible that with lots of instances of al.exe running, is it possible they run concurrently, and since they seem to take the "next" available RES*.tmp filename, that they clash. Or alternatively, it runs so quickly that occasionally by the time the next one runs, the file system hasn't updated in time to reflect that the previous one has already created a particular file, and it likewise clashes? I'm wondering if msbuild could be told to space out the calls to al.exe somehow.

Hi @komodosp, you can try to add -maxcpucount:1 to the msbuild command to stop MSBuild from running in parallel. By the way, I also found this question with the same Error Message: CVT1108. It is solved by giving full control of the Temp folder to the account and you can have a try.

@MiaoTian-MSFT - thanks for your help - I've made the -maxcpucount:1 change and so far so good, but as I said it's intermittent so it will be a while before I know if it worked! Regarding the other question - the account already has full control of the Temp folder, and I would think that if that was the problem it would fail every time rather than just randomly as it does now - it can create & delete lots of these RES...tmp files without a problem before randomly falling over.

Thanks for your reminder and update. I didn't noticed that this issue was an occasional occurrence in pipeline.  Looking forward to your update on monitoring it for a few days to see if the -maxcpucount:1 can help you resolve this issue.

Hi @komodosp, it has been several days since we discuss the issue.  Can the -maxcpucount:1 help with this issue?

@MiaoTian-MSFT - yeah it looks like this has done the trick, thanks for the suggestion - if you post this as an answer I will accept it

Hi @komodosp, glad to hear that this works. I have added the answer. Happy coding! :)

According to our discussion in the comments, you noticed an unusual RES*.tmp file behavior with al.exe, and are considering if msbuild could be told to space out the calls to al.exe somehow.
So, I suggest you add -maxcpucount:1 to the msbuild command to stop MSBuild from running in parallel. It looks like this has done the trick after monitoring it for a few days.
